# How to speed up a module function with a large number of arguments?

Tags: performance-tuning, scoping, arguments

I'm setting up a fairly hefty numerical code dealing with matrices 
 of variable dimension, but on the order of hundreds of rows and columns.

I'm using a Module format:

```
function[vals_]:=Module[{args=vals},
<<Code>>
]
```

In the past when I've had say, 3 arguments in my function I've ensured Mathematica knows what to expect w.r.t numerics:

```
function[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ, v3_?NumericQ]:=

Module[{a1=v1, a2= v2, a3=v3},

<<Code>>
]
```

However now I have *eighteen* variables and I don't want to have to type them out each individually... and it will become very, very confusing calling the function with different values. A solution I thought of was to group each class of variables (for example, there are 4x coupling strengths and 4x coupling times - grouping in coupling strengths and times) such that the function can be called like

```
function[l1_?ListQ, l2_?ListQ, l3_?ListQ]:=

Module[{},
]
```

However then using Module becomes obsolete as I'm not sure how to assign the local variables in terms of the lists, NOR am I sure how to force Mathematica to only accept numerical values in each of the lists.

Anyone have any ideas on writing Modules with a high number of arguments?

Comment: Functions already localise their variables, what does Module give you here?

Comment: You can use the second argument of `VectorQ` to force MAthematica to only accept numerical values.

Comment: KraZug made a very good point! I would also suggest to use `Association`s with human-readable `Key`s for variable passing such as `fancyhead /: function[fancyhead[a_Association]]:= ...` with arguments of the form `fancyhead[Association["bla"-> somematrix, "bli" -> someothermatrix, "blubb" -> yetanothermatrix, ...]`. This way, you also don't have to care about the ordering of the arguments. You can access the matrices in the body of `function`, e.g. by `a["blubb"]`.

Comment: `MatrixQ` and `ArrayQ` in their two-argument version might also be relevent here.

Comment: @KraZug Historical reasons mainly. This code has been developing over several years for different projects, the initial ones were all regular functions - at some point the computation time became too large and switching to Module seemed to rectify that! Applying `(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)` appears to be a fix, I may remove this question!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher interesting use of Association! I'll look into it! Thank you